# force Oracle to use indexes over DB-Link queries

Tags: oracle, database-indexes, dblink

I use stored proceduers on DB instance "A" to store data in GTT. To get the original data i have to go over a DB-Link to DB instance "B". That for i put together the whole query and send it to remote DB instance.

This works fine. But sometimes it seems that Oracle is not using the best way or correct indexes for queries. Is there a way to force Oracle to use specific indexes? I tried to use hints, but honestly I dind't understand the difference between all these options.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge temptation to optimize a query one way when you want it to work another way. Adding hints is a temporary solution which can backfire on you when the amount or type of data in the table changes or when you upgrade to a newer version with a newer optimizer.

First, determine that there is a problem.  Are all queries taking too long?  Just some? Only the first one?

The easiest thing to do is to make sure the indexes on that table are up to date. Then look at optimizing the query by using the [explain plan feature](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=explain-plan-over-db-link) to see what indexes are being used.

It's also prudent to examine your data to see if the query is selecting different things or different amounts of records if it is time based.